# Updating apt breaks my docker build on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, apt

I'm running into problems updating `apt` from within docker. Currently I have the whole dockerfile commented out except for this:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt update
```

Basically I have to do `apt update` first because without it the ubuntu package manager does not work. However, this line is breaking my docker build:

```
(pyomexmeta-test) ciaran@DESKTOP-K0APGUV:/mnt/d/libOmexMeta$ DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t  pyomexmeta:v-0.0.13 .
[+] Building 7.6s (5/5) FINISHED
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                         0.1s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                      0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.04kB                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:18.04                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:18.04                                                                                                      0.0s
 => ERROR [2/2] RUN APT update                                                                                                                            7.5s
------
 > [2/2] RUN    APT update:
#5 0.240
#5 0.240 WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
#5 0.240
#5 0.355 Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]
#5 0.495 Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
#5 0.558 Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
#5 0.649 Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
#5 0.742 Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [1344 kB]
#5 1.323 Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse amd64 Packages [186 kB]
#5 1.392 Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages [11.3 MB]
#5 6.281 Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted amd64 Packages [13.5 kB]
#5 6.897 Reading package lists...
#5 7.438 E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 19h 35min 45s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
#5 7.438 E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 19h 37min 17s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
#5 7.438 E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 19h 34min 38s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt update]: runc did not terminate sucessfully
(pyomexmeta-test) ciaran@DESKTOP-K0APGUV:/mnt/d/libOmexMeta$ echo $http_proxy
```

I've also tried without the `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` variable with the same results (albeit slower).

I'm guessing this is something basic since I'm new to docker, but could somebody suggest how I can update apt without it breaking my build?

Comment: Are you behind proxy? or ca you try with `FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update` or `RUN apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false -o Acquire::Check-Date=false update`

Comment: That's really strange - using `apt-get update` worked but `apt` does not. I was under the impression that they were the same thing. Anyway - thanks, certainly wouldn't have figured that one out alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `apt-get update` and it should work or you can check timezone if that did not work.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
apt-get update
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why `apt-get` worked but `apt` does not?

Comment: I did not found any documentation that I can refer but that was based on my experienced inside docker installation. but with `apt` you might notice warning regarding interface stablity but I do not think that can create issue so suggestion was based on my experience

Comment: For me both `apt` and `apt-get` gives the same error as above

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comment by @Adiii this worked for me :

```
apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false -o Acquire::Check-Date=false update
```